# remove all dependencies of a jar within a maven assembly

Tags: java, maven, zip

I am trying to create a zip file that includes two folders each folder will contain a plugin of a certain dependency within the pom. I am currently able to create the correct structure but I would like to make sure that the jar of the first dependency for example does not fall within that of the second.
my current pom structure is as follows:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>PARENT-GROUP</groupId>
        <artifactId>PARENT-ARTIFACT</artifactId>
        <version>0.2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>GROUP-ID</groupId>
    <artifactId>ARTIFACT-ID</artifactId>

    <properties>
        <main.project>MAIN-PROJECT</main.project>
        <plugin.version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</plugin.version>
        <plugin.artifact>PLUGIN-ID</plugin.artifact>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>PLUGIN-GROUP</groupId>
            <artifactId>${plugin.artifact}</artifactId>
            <version>${plugin.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>SECOND-DEPENDENCY</groupId>
            <artifactId>SECOND-ARTIFACT-ID</artifactId>
            <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>${main.project}-${project.parent.version}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                    <descriptors>
                        <descriptor>${project.basedir}/src/zip.xml</descriptor>
                    </descriptors>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

As can be seen I have two dependencies within the pom that I am getting. The output I would like to have is the following folder structure
main\lib: contains the second dependency jar with all it's dependencies within the same folder.
main\plugin\plugin: contains all of the first dependency (the plugin and all it's dependency) both folders should not include the dependency of the first and vice versa. So far I have come up with the following assembly xml

```
<assembly
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.0.xsd">
    <id>release</id>
    <formats>
        <format>zip</format>
    </formats>
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
    <dependencySets>
        <dependencySet>
            <outputDirectory>/lib</outputDirectory>
            <unpack>false</unpack>
            <useProjectArtifact>false</useProjectArtifact>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>
                    *:${plugin.artifact}
                </exclude>
            </excludes>
        </dependencySet>
        <dependencySet>
            <outputDirectory>/plugins/${plugin.artifact}-${plugin.version}/${plugin.artifact}-${plugin.version}</outputDirectory>
            <unpack>false</unpack>
            <useProjectArtifact>false</useProjectArtifact>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>
                    *:SECOND-ARTIFACT-ID
                </exclude>
            </excludes>
        </dependencySet>
    </dependencySets>
</assembly>
```

This give me the write folder structure but includes the dependencies in both I would like to know if there is a better way to exclude the dependencies of each of the jars automatically instead of excluding them one by one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Helping other people with the solution if they are looking for it. All you will need to perform is adding within the dependencySet an extra tag user transitive filtering and set it to true.

```
<dependencySet>
    <outputDirectory>/lib</outputDirectory>
    <unpack>false</unpack>
    <useProjectArtifact>false</useProjectArtifact>
    <useTransitiveFiltering>true</useTransitiveFiltering>
    <excludes>
        <exclude>
            *:${plugin.artifact}
        </exclude>
    </excludes>
</dependencySet>
```

this will make sure that the excludes dependencies are filtered.